# Android PhoneGap app not sizing content like equivalent Chrome/browser page does

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, svg

I have created a web page using HTML5, Javascript and a lot of SVG graphics.  It works fine on the native Android browser and the latest Chrome browser on my Android tablet.

I've wrapped my application in PhoneGap and deployed it in the emulator.  Everything is OK.  Then I deployed it on the tablet.  I'm not getting the same results.

When my META tag contains "target-densitydpi="device-dpi" my SVG graphics calculate themselves as large as they do in the browser, but the text is about half size.

I'm told that target-densitydpi is deprecated, so I'm trying to figure out how to do this right.

I have this activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this META:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

In my window.onload() I perform calculations to resize my SVG graphics:

```
var minWindowDim = Math.min(window.screen.availWidth, window.screen.availHeight)
var maxWindowDim = Math.max(window.screen.availWidth, window.screen.availHeight)
var minEffectiveDim = Math.min(minWindowDim, (maxWindowDim / 1.5));
var minDim = minEffectiveDim * AVID.avidSizeFactor;

var avidWrapper = document.getElementById("avidWrapper");
avidWrapper.setAttribute("height", minDim);
avidWrapper.setAttribute("width", minDim);
```

The avidWrapper is a SVG nominally 318 pixels square.  That is why height and width are set the same.

I put in some alerts to tell me what is going on.

In the desktop Chrome browser:

```
window.screen.availWidth: 1600
window.screen.availHeight: 860
minWindowDim: 860
maxWindowDim: 1600
minEffectiveDim: 860
minDim: 817   // This is 95% of minEffectiveDim.
avidWrapper.clientWidth: 318
```

I then resize width and height from 318 to 817 and I'm happy.

On Chrome in the tablet:

```
window.screen.availWidth: 601
window.screen.availHeight: 906
minWindowDim: 601
maxWindowDim: 906
minEffectiveDim: 601
minDim: 570.95   // This is 95% of minEffectiveDim.
avidWrapper.clientWidth: 318
```

As a PhoneGap app on the tablet:

```
window.screen.availWidth: 800
window.screen.availHeight: 1206
minWindowDim: 800
maxWindowDim: 1206
minEffectiveDim: 800
minDim: 760.95   // This is 95% of minEffectiveDim.
avidWrapper.clientWidth: 318
```

When expanded the avidWrapper extends beyond the borders of the device, requiring a scroll to see everything.

The intent of the calculation is to constrain things.  PhoneGap is seeing numbers that are (800 / 600 =) 1.33 what Chrome is seeing.  I don't see any 1.33, or 0.75, in the source of my PhoneGap project (written through Eclipse).  And I'm not sure if there is a "virtual pixel size" going on here.

Can someone with Android or PhoneGap tell me where to look to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Jerome.

UPDATE 2/11/14, 9 AM:

I've discovered window.devicePixelRatio, and for my tablet it is 1.33.  This matches the difference between Chrome and PhoneGap.

I can add that factor to my calculation at startup in a PhoneGap app.  My questions pivot to a related issue.  Why does Chrome report the size in CSS pixels?  I'll do some measurements later today.  Perhaps window.screen.availWidth is the wrong measure...

Comment: This may help you [PhoneGap app is unresponsive on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128514/phonegap-app-is-unresponsive-on-android)